# Using the Facebook API, how do I retrieve the campaign tags I have assigned to a campaign in ads manager?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I define a test campaign and give it a campaign tag like so:

[campaign with tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhgeI.png)

The Id of this campaign is 120203162837850073 as illustrated here:

[campaign id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ex5M.png)

I can easily access the id, name, and other information about this campaign via the api as so:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfto5.png)

I need this information to include the campaign tag I just added, as I plan to use those tags to differentiate what environment a campaign belongs to.   How do I do this?

I tried field=adlabels and that isn't it.  The documentation doesn't mention tags at all.  Where are they?